# Delete column and Add column with default value Amplify graphql DynamoDB Appsync

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I want to delete the whole column at once if there 1000's of data deleting one by one is time consuming so is there any best way to do it

[Deleting this column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlkQu.png)

And my next question is I need to add new column with default value aftering deleting

i.e :

### id |  x  | y |  z

1. |  A  | B |  C
2. |  A  | B |  C
3. |  A  | B |  C
4. |  A  | B |  C

If above is the the table with thousands of data , I want to delete "z" and add "newColumn" with default value of "D" as below

### id |  x |  y |  newColumn

1. |  A |  B |   D
2. |  A |  B |   D
3. |  A |  B |   D
4. |  A |  B |   D